# sscanf and %i / radix detection of large unsigned integers

Tags: c, scanf, unsigned, unsigned-integer

I'm working with files containing large numbers (disk offsets) and have run into a problem using `scanf` for `%lli` - the numbers are of the format `0x`... but `scanf` doesn't read all the bits.

Here's example code (I tested on https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char* str = malloc(30);
    unsigned long long l;
    sprintf(str, "0x%llx\n", 0xffffffffffffffffULL);
    printf("%s\n", str);
    sscanf(str, "%lli", &l);
    printf("%llx\n", l);

    return 0;
}
```

It outputs:

```
0xffffffffffffffff

7fffffffffffffff
```

whereas I expect both numbers to be equal.

If I use the `%llx` specifier, it works properly, but I don't want to limit myself to hex-formatted numbers.

Comment: try [`strtoull()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtoul.html)

Comment: @png Thanks - it works, but 'm scanning multiple tokens at once. That would complicate all my code.

Comment: It's better if you use `snprintf()` instead of `sprintf()` to avoid overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately `i` stands for **signed** integer, and the corresponding expected argument is a pointer to `int`; with `ll` the width will be `long long`, but it would still be signed. There is no `scanf` format character for unsigned integer with base detection.

---

There is no perfect solution. You can use `strtoull(str, &endptr, 0)` (or even `strtoumax`), which will detect the format correctly, but it is much more tedious to use.

But `scanf` is not perfect either - if the number is too big, then you would always get the maximum value, just like you got `LLONG_MAX`, without error indication.

Comment: maybe add the alternative of `strtoull` from @pmg's comment and I'll mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score -1):

`%lli` is for `long long signed int` (which only goes up to 0x7fffffffffffffff on your system).

`%llu` is for `long long unsigned int` (which is what you are trying to read).

Replace the former for the latter.